# How two recursive numbers stored as doubles sum up to an integer

Tags: java, int, double

This is just out of curiosity. If I store two recursive numbers or irrational numbers in two doubles and then perform some operations, how does it produce actual result?

For example,

```
double d1=7d/3;
double d2=5d/3;
double sum=d1+d2;
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(sum)); //prints exactly 4
```

Another one:

```
double d1=log10(3);
double value=Math.pow(10,d1);
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(value)); //prints exactly 3
```

How these accurate results are generated?

Comment: @MitchWheat I just checked and it is not in this case.

Comment: no, it's just System.out.print(sum);

Comment: can you provide code how you are printing?

Comment: @VictorMukherjee `println` does print a rounded double in some occasions, but not in this case. I have added a line that prints the exact result to your example.

Comment: @assylias: I am still getting sum=4 and value=3 with the new BigDecimal(value)

Comment: @VictorMukherjee Yes the point was to show that there was no rounding due to printing the double with println.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you amend your code slightly you will see that `d1` and `d2` are not exactly `7/3` or `5/3`. The reason why `d1+d2` is exactly `4` is that `4` can be represented exactly as a double and is the closest to the exact result of this addition.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    double d1 = 7d / 3;
    double d2 = 5d / 3;
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal(d1)); //2.333333333333333481363069950020872056484222412109375
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal(d2)); //1.6666666666666667406815349750104360282421112060546875
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal(d1).add(new BigDecimal(d2))); //4.0000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625
    double sum = d1 + d2; 
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal(sum)); //4
}
```

Java [follows the IEEE 754 convention](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2-500):

> the sum is rounded to the nearest value in the chosen value set using IEEE 754 round-to-nearest mode